# Managing dependent state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have following state:

```
{
    programmeCodes,  // generated from asynch resource
    programmeColors   // depends on programmeCodes
}
```

and following actions for asynch resource:

```
export const REQUEST_PROGRAMME_CODES = 'REQUEST_PROGRAMME_CODES'
export const RECEIVE_PROGRAMME_CODES = 'RECEIVE_PROGRAMME_CODES'

function requestProgrammeCodes() {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_PROGRAMME_CODES,
  }
}

export function fetchProgrammeCodes() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestProgrammeCodes())

    return api.fetchProgrammes()
      .then(
        response => response,
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
      )
      .then(json =>
        dispatch(receiveProgrammeCodes(json))
      )
  }
}

function shouldFetchProgrammeCodes(state) {
  const codes = state.programmeCodes.codes.length > 0

  if (!codes) {
    return true
  } else if (codes.isFetching) {
    return false
  } else {
    return codes.didInvalidate
  }
}

export function fetchProgrammeCodesIfNeeded() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchProgrammeCodes(getState())) {
      // Dispatch a thunk from thunk!
      return dispatch(fetchProgrammeCodes())
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve()
    }
  }
}
```

'programmeCodes' is a dependency needed to generate 'programmeColors'.
Id like (with good practice) to be able to request 'programmeColors' in a React component without worrying about whether programmeCodes have been received or not.

**How do I write actions for 'programmeColors' to achieve the above?**

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you can just set a default state, e.g. empty and render 'loading' or something when state is empty in your component.

Comment: @tomasz the idea is that you just want to request programmeColors, and disregard the existence of programmeCodes in the React Component. I think your solution would involve mapping both programmeCodes & programmeColors to the component, which is NOT what I'm after.